# Using WP Child Theme to override a PHP file within sub directories of main WP theme

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the file hierarchy:
Main Theme>PageBuilder>Blocks>campaigns-block.php

I edited the campaigns-block.php to suit my needs & now want to place it in my Child Theme to override. The Main Theme's campaigns-block.php file.

How might I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in the child theme you can only automatically override parts of the Template Heirarchy (`header.php`, `page.php`, etc.) You would need to override the template file that includes `campaigns-block.php` and direct it to your copy in the child theme folder.

See this answer for more details:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62341/override-file-in-parent-theme